# Sum for a large dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large SparseDataFrame, approximately 12000 rows x 16000 columns. I want to calculate sum of rows grouped by a column:

Input:

```
+-------+------+------+------+
|       | Col1 | Col2 | Col3 |
+-------+------+------+------+
| row 1 | Foo  |    1 |    0 |
| row 2 | Foo  |    3 |    1 |
| row 3 | Bar  |    5 |    3 |
+-------+------+------+------+
```

Output:

```
+-----+------+------+
|     | Col2 | Col3 |
+-----+------+------+
| Foo |    4 |    1 |
| Bar |    5 |    3 |
+-----+------+------+
```

Any ideas how to make this code more performant? Currently it works very slow.

```
sparse_df = pd.SparseDataFrame(vector, columns=data).transpose() 
sparse_df.groupby('col1').sum()
```

Answer (score 2):

This should be fast than `groupby`

```
df.set_index('Col1').sum(level=0)
Out[294]: 
      Col2  Col3
Col1            
Foo      4     1
Bar      5     3
```

Comment: I'm getting `ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has xxxx elements, new values have yyyy elements` when I do `set_index`

Comment: @KertisvanKertis you have NaN in col1 ?

Comment: Yes. NaN and other duplicate values.

Comment: @KertisvanKertis you can do df.Col1=df.Col1.fillna('NaN') before above code